# IIS URL Rewrite multiple parameters

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I am really confused about the URL rewrite interface. I dont understand what i need to do. 
I have an url as:

```
www.example.com/diretory/subdirectory/index.html?param1=1&param2=2&param3=2&param4=7
```

I want to hide this url in a `<a>`-href tag, which displays "Example Tag". 
When the url is requested it should rewrite it to

```
www.example.com/program/location/year/vacancie
```

I allready tried this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ProgramRewrite" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="\?([^/]+)&amp;([^/]+)&amp;([^/]+)&amp;([^/]+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="www.example.com/program/location/year/vacancie" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                <conditions>
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

In the URL Rewrite Interface the `Test Pattern` said it is working and gets:

```
?param1=1&param2=2&param3=2&param4=7
param1=1
param2=2
param3=2
param4=7
```

I checked the log url rewrite as well, but in my logs it is not shown.

```
2017-03-20 16:29:24 192.168.253.146 GET /diretory/subdirectory/index.html param1=1&param2=2&param3=2&param4=7 88 - 192.168.253.146 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 304 0 0 4
```

ps: the urls are not working and only for illustrative purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The match URL only matches the URL and does not take the querystring into account. You will need to add a condition for this. Also do you want to rewrite this (so the server internally executes the new URL) or redirect (so the server will request the browser to go to the new URL and URL changes in address bar). In case you want to rewrite you should not add the domain again, in case you want to redirect add http:// as well. Assuming a rewrite is what you want use below rule:

```
 <rule name="ProgramRewrite" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/program/location/year/vacancie" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="([^/]+)&amp;([^/]+)&amp;([^/]+)&amp;([^/]+)" />
            </conditions>
        </rule>
```

Comment: It is allmost the answer. I got something wrong in my mind with url-rewriting. I want that the user can open `www.example.com/program/location/year/vacancie` and it opens `www.example.com/diretory/subdirectory/index.html?param1=1&param2=2&param3=2&param4=7`, but still shows `www.example.com/program/location/year/vacancie` in the browser as url. Is this possible ?

Comment: I see, so you want to match /program/location/year/vacancie and then internally send it to /diretory/subdirectory/index.html?param1=1&pa‌​ram2=2&param3=2&para‌​m4=7 ?

Comment: If that is what you want that is actually alot easier:
 <rule name="ProgramRewrite" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^program/location/year/vacancie$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="diretory/subdirectory/index.html?param1=1&amp;param2=2&amp;param3=2&amp;param4=7" />
                
            </rule>

Comment: Ok, that is redirecting me correctly. In addition: Do i need to refer to my Scripts with a static href, because of the url, it do not find them.

Comment: And how i can read the Url Parameters on the rewritten url ? Cause i need them in my script. I need to work with param1/2/3/4 to get the right data on the page.

Comment: This is a little tricky since the rewrite happens completely server side. I think there are 2 ways to do that. Either duplicate the logic in javascript. The other way will avoid having this logic but will require you to install ARR and add an outbound rule to add a response header or something similar that you can read in script. https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing